# I am having trouble with a program that consist of moving the purple box left, right, etc

Tags: c#

This is what I have so far:

```
namespace C2360_Ch06_07_Hmwk1_MoveIt
{
    public partial class frmMoveit : Form
    {
        int X = 0;
        int Y = 0;
        public frmMoveit()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int currX = btnBox.Location.X;
            int curry = btnBox.Location.Y;
            btnBox.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        }

        private void btnEight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button myButton;

            myButton = (Button)sender;
            
            if (myButton == btnL)
            {
                btnBox.Left = 5;
            }
        
            else if(myButton == btnR)
            {
               btnBox.Right = 5;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what I am looking to do is try to set `btnBox` to go left, right, down, up, up left, up right, down left, down right moving 5 spaces. From what you see, I ran the program and it moves all the way to the left.

In addition, I'm looking to set the position of x and y to 0 as well as set the width and height to 25, default, when typed on the text box. Then resize the `btnBox` to a new width and height when typed in the text box and clicking the resize button.

Hope I made this clear for anyone that can assist me.

Comment: What happens if you try using `Location` directly instead of `Left` or `Right`?